# request.form get element value based on class

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

If i have blocks of html like this

```
   <div class="firstblock">
       <input type="text" name="txtName"/>
       ...

   </div>

   <div class="secondblock">
       <input type="text" name="txtName"/>
       ...

   </div>
```

on asp.net code behind how will i use Request.Form to get the text box values? In 
  other words,how do i identify whether the textbox belong to the firsblock or secondblock?
  Lets assume the text boxes will have same name attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: can't they have different IDs?

Comment: my idea was to clone similar blocks like above without id's (using jquery clone), but with different class names

Comment: I think that Request.Form collection gives you only flat list of items based on name

Comment: There is no relationship, the server only sees posted values from the form. Why do you need to know what block the form control is in? If you really need this, create your own convention where you associate the `input`'s name attribute with a custom HTML5 `data-*` attribute on the `div`.

Comment: Chris, i would need to know which textbox it is, so that i can capture it and store it in an appropriate field in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get Request.Form values based on a html class attribute on its own tag or a parent tag.

To get a unique key for your values, you have to use unique names for each input tags.

If you don't want that, you can use JavaScript to get the values of the input tags and submit them to the server via Ajax giving it keys taken from the class attributes of their parent tags. But that's much more work.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will have to find another way now to duplicate my blocks with unique ids.